# Pushing to Artifactory (Jenkins Pipelines, Maven and Java 6)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory, java-6

I've just been brought onto a quite old, long-going project that uses Java 6 and I'm trying to improve their current build process.

Currently, they use an old version of Jenkins and multi-job projects and I'd like to migrate that to pipelines.

I'm using a slave with Java 8 enabled by default and then enabling Java 6 for Maven to run the build.

```
withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${env.JAVA6_HOME}", 'MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"']) {
    sh "${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/mvn clean install -f bla/pom.xml"
}
```

This results in about 90 jar files that need to be pushed to the repo.

Because we need to use Java 6, following these instructions[1] and running the Maven build using the Artifactory plugin won't work, as it needs Java 7 to run.

To work around it, I'm pushing the artifacts using this[2]:

```
def pushToArtifactory(version, fileType, repo) {

    uploadSpec = """{
        "files": [
            {
                "pattern": "**/target/*-${version}.${fileType}",
                "target": "${repo}"
            }
        ]
}"""

    server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory'

    buildInfo = server.upload(uploadSpec)
    println(buildInfo)
    server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
}
```

This worked almost fine, in the sense that it pushed the expected JARs to the repo, but it didn't follow any structure. They're all under the root folder of the repo. There's no version information and no POMs, so I'm guessing Artifactory is not automatically reading the POM withing the JARs.

I'm sure I must be missing something quite obvious the artifacts are actually published as `group.id:artifact.id:version.number` and also publish their POMs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

[1] https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+-+Working+With+the+Pipeline+Jenkins+Plugin#Artifactory-WorkingWiththePipelineJenkinsPlugin-MavenBuildswithArtifactory

[2]https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+-+Working+With+the+Pipeline+Jenkins+Plugin#Artifactory-WorkingWiththePipelineJenkinsPlugin-UploadingandDownloadingFiles

Comment: Why not using simply `mvn clean deploy`? instead of `mvn clean install`?

Comment: I totally agree, but the team will not change the way they do things, at least not quickly. `mvn clean deploy` is not an option. Changing to pipelines is the only thing they'll accept for now.

Comment: The File Spec you defined uploads the files to Artifactory in a flat layout. Adding to the spec the "flat" property with a "false" value as described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs) will preserve the local file-system structure.

Comment: Thanks @EyalBenMoshe. I'm not sure that would help me. What I'm trying to do is push to Artifactory so the tree is in the "shape" of a Maven repo. So it should look:
`groupid/artifactid/version/artifact.jar`
`groupid/artifactid/version/pom.xml`

I've managed to do this in a very dirty way, which is adding an array of files to `uploadSpec` so the `pattern` matches single files and puts them in the right place with the `target`.  This generates quite a big json to pass to Artifactory and it takes around 15 minutes to upload. Using the old version of the plugin takes them 1 minute. Any ideas?

Comment: @davidfm, Another workaround can be to configure the [Maven Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) and then run *mvn deploy* from within the Pipeline script.

Comment: All solved using my previous workaround and upgrading the Jenkins plugin. It now takes 15 seconds.